# Install page running in live environment

Tags: magento-1.9

A couple of weeks ago we moved a Magento (1.9) to another server. Everything works well untill suddenly we experienced the shop throwing the install page back. Going to the homepage would temporarily redirect to the /install instance which was actually a bit shocking. In an attempt to solve this we emptied the caches immediately and after a few minutes the normal page came back (with some switch the first 5 minutes between the homepage and the install page).

To be honest I really don't know if this actually solved the problem or if it even has some relation between eachother. As said, I haven't experienced anything like this before and I'm very curious on how to prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

install magento patch:

> Magento Install Page Displays After SOAP v2 Index Page Refresh Patch
>   name: SUPEE-3762. Refreshing the SOAP v2 index page
>   (http://your-magento-host-name/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/) results
>   in all administrators and customers viewing the Magento installation
>   page.

Comment: Isn't this patch already included in the Magento 1.9 package?

Comment: I'm also not able to download this patch anymore from the Magento website

Comment: you have to debug it yourself

Comment: I did find the patch and we do use the SOAP API. At least you've pointed me in the right direction. Hope this solves it.